# Can't Print User Defined Function in C

Tags: c, printf, user-defined-functions

Every time when I try to print returned value of user-defined function, my code fail to print the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int *d = NULL;
int **M = NULL;
int **P = NULL;

int minimult(int n, int *d, int **P)
{
    int i, j, k, diagonal;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        M[i][i] = 0;

    for (diagonal = 1; diagonal <= n - 1; diagonal++)
        for (i = 1; i <= n - diagonal; i++)
        {
            j = i + diagonal;
        
            int *min = NULL;
            M[i][j] = min[0];

            for (k = i; k < j; k++)
            {
                min[k] = (M[i][k] + M[k + 1][j] + d[i - 1] * d[k] * d[j]);

                if (min[k] < min[k + 1])
                    M[i][j] = min[k];
                else
                    M[i][j] = min[k + 1];
            }
        }

    return **M;
    return **P;
}


void order(int i, int j)
{
    int k;

    if (i == j)
        printf("A%d\n", i);

    else
    {
        k = P[i][j];
        printf("(");
        order(i, k);
        order(k + 1, j);
        printf(")");
    }

}


int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int input;

    printf("Write the size of matrices.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    M = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        M = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }

    printf("Input array d with %d elements.\n", n + 1);
    d = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        d[i] = input;
    }    

    free(M);
    free(d);


    int minimult(int n, int *d, int **P);

    printf("The minimum size of multiplication is,\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", M[i][j]);
        }
    }

    void order(i, j);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, all I can see is :

> Write the size of matrices.
>
> (scanf)
>
> Input array d with (inputOfScanf) elements.
>
> (scanf)
>
> The minimum size of multiplication is,

...and the program ends.

What did I do wrong?

How can I see array M and solution of *order* function?

Comment: Are you using `M` right after you `free`d it? You also do not call function, you just declare them.

Comment: Why are you calling `free(M)` before printing out the contents?

Comment: On an unrelated problem, you can't have multiple return values from a function. Once a single `return` statement is reached, it will return immediately from the function. Any possible following return won't be reached.

Comment: Also, `M = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` inside the loop is wrong. You want `M[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`

Comment: All in all, you have so many problems that it seems you're *guessing* about things, not really knowing them. So before you continue, go back to the very beginning, get a few books (or even go take classes) and learn properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Your comments really helped me fixing my code.
Like what you said, I oughta go study from the very basic...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you start much, much simpler.  There is a lot going on in the program you've presented, but as @Some programmer dude pointed out in the comments, the problems are much more fundamental than the lack of output.

For example, start with this, which is a small portion of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    int n;
    int **M = NULL;

    printf("Write the size of matrices.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    M = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        M = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("matrix element #%d is %d\n", i, *M[i]);
    }
}
```

When run, this segfaults inside the 2nd loop, trying to access `*M[i]`.  This is because, as one of the comments points out, in the 1st loop you really want:

```
M[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

With this fix, the program runs, and outputs e.g. :

```
Write the size of matrices.
5
matrix element #0 is 0
matrix element #1 is 0
matrix element #2 is 0
matrix element #3 is 0
matrix element #4 is 0
```

From there, you can add **a little bit at a time**, and verify that what is happening is what you expect to happen by printing out **everything** along the way.  Eventually, as you proceed, you will be able to drop some of the earlier printout statements, so that the output focuses on just the part you recently added or modified.

You can build slowly back up the function you are trying to write, but there are lots of fundamentals you need to understand first.  **Start simple, make small additions, and output everything.**  This will help you understand your code, and let you see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to deal with the array problem!I'll try adding some code step by step with your advice.